# Is there an embeddable/embedded feature in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Java Persistence API (JPA) supports `@Embeddable` objects in entities.
Is there a similar feature in Entity Framework Core or a way to achieve this behavior in EF Core?

Comment: Maybe EF core 7 complex property,?

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ This seems like an option. Unfortunately, complex properties cannot be used as navigation properties yet.

Comment: ... and it cannot contain navigation properties itself

Comment: ... and it doesn't support seeding